# Are all Regular Graphs Simple?

Tags: graph-theory

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is it always assumed that regular graphs are always simple? Or is this too presumptuous? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by simple?  Loopless, no parallel edges? or in some algebraic sense?

Comment: There can certainly be multi-graphs (having parallel edges) that are regular.  Take a cycle on $n$ vertices where every pair of edges (along the cycle) is duplicated to some fixed number of parallel edges.  That is a regular graph that is not simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In graph theory, [regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) essentially implies that all the degrees are the same.  So we can have regular [multigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph), [digraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), [hypergraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph), and so on.

Here are some examples:

[image: example of other regular graphs]

(I'm not good at drawing regular hypergraphs.)